# Apply a function to groupBy data with pyspark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I'm trying to get word counts from a csv when grouping on another column. My csv has three columns: id, message and user_id. I read this in and then split the message and store a list of unigrams:

```
+-----------------+--------------------+--------------------+
|               id|             message|             user_id|
+-----------------+--------------------+--------------------+
|10100720363468236|[i'm, sad, to, mi...|dceafb541a1b8e894...|
|10100718944611636|[what, does, the,...|dceafb541a1b8e894...|
|10100718890699676|[at, the, oecd, w...|dceafb541a1b8e894...|
+-----------------+--------------------+--------------------+
```

Next, given my dataframe `df`, I want to group by `user_id` and then get counts for each of the unigrams. As a simple first pass I tried grouping by `user_id` and get the length of the grouped message field:

```py
from collections import Counter
from pyspark.sql.types import ArrayType, StringType, IntegerType
from pyspark.sql.functions import udf

df = self.session.read.csv(self.corptable, header=True,
        mode="DROPMALFORMED",)

# split my messages ....
# message is now ArrayType(StringType())

grouped = df.groupBy(df["user_id"])
counter = udf(lambda l: len(l), ArrayType(StringType()))
grouped.agg(counter(df["message"]))
print(grouped.collect())
```

I get the following error:

```
pyspark.sql.utils.AnalysisException: "expression '`message`' is neither present in the group by, nor is it an aggregate function. Add to group by or wrap in first() (or first_value) if you don't care which value you get.;"
```

Not sure how to get around this error. In general how does one apply a function to one column when grouping another? Do I always have to create a User Defined Function? Very new to Spark.

**Edit**: Here is how I solved this, given a tokenizer in a separate Python file:

```py
group_field = "user_id"
message_field = "message"

context = SparkContext()
session = SparkSession\
        .builder\
        .appName("dlastk")\
        .getOrCreate()

# add tokenizer
context.addPyFile(tokenizer_path)
from tokenizer import Tokenizer
tokenizer = Tokenizer()
spark_tokenizer = udf(tokenizer.tokenize, ArrayType(StringType()))

df = session.read.csv("myFile.csv", header=True,)
df = df[group_field, message_field]

# tokenize the message field
df = df.withColumn(message_field, spark_tokenizer(df[message_field]))

# create ngrams from tokenized messages
n = 1
grouped = df.rdd.map(lambda row: (row[0], Counter([" ".join(x) for x in zip(*[row[1][i:] for i in range(n)])]))).reduceByKey(add)

# flatten the rdd so that each row contains (group_id, ngram, count, relative frequency
flat = grouped.flatMap(lambda row: [[row[0], x,y, y/sum(row[1].values())] for x,y in row[1].items()])

# rdd -> DF
flat = flat.toDF()
flat.write.csv("myNewCSV.csv")
```

Data looks like:

```
# after read
+--------------------+--------------------+
|             user_id|             message|
+--------------------+--------------------+
|00035fb0dcfbeaa8b...|To the douchebag ...|
|00035fb0dcfbeaa8b...|   T minus 1 week...|
|00035fb0dcfbeaa8b...|Last full day of ...|
+--------------------+--------------------+

# after tokenize
+--------------------+--------------------+
|             user_id|             message|
+--------------------+--------------------+
|00035fb0dcfbeaa8b...|[to, the, doucheb...|
|00035fb0dcfbeaa8b...|[t, minus, 1, wee...|
|00035fb0dcfbeaa8b...|[last, full, day,...|
+--------------------+--------------------+

# grouped: after 1grams extracted and Counters added
[('00035fb0dcfbeaa8bb70ffe24d614d4dcee446b803eb4063dccf14dd2a474611', Counter({'!': 545, '.': 373, 'the': 306, '"': 225, ...

# flat: after calculating sum and relative frequency for each 1gram
[['00035fb0dcfbeaa8bb70ffe24d614d4dcee446b803eb4063dccf14dd2a474611', 'face', 3, 0.000320547066994337], ['00035fb0dcfbeaa8bb70ffe24d614d4dcee446b803eb4063dccf14dd2a474611', 'was', 26, 0.002778074580617587] ....

# after flat RDD to DF
+--------------------+---------+---+--------------------+
|                  _1|       _2| _3|                  _4|
+--------------------+---------+---+--------------------+
|00035fb0dcfbeaa8b...|     face|  3| 3.20547066994337E-4|
|00035fb0dcfbeaa8b...|      was| 26|0.002778074580617587|
|00035fb0dcfbeaa8b...|      how| 22|0.002350678491291...|
+--------------------+---------+---+--------------------+
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

A natural approach could be to group the words into one list, and then use the python function `Counter()` to generate word counts. For both steps we'll use `udf`'s. First, the one that will flatten the nested list resulting from `collect_list()` of multiple arrays:

```py
unpack_udf = udf(
    lambda l: [item for sublist in l for item in sublist]
)
```

Second, one that generates the word count tuples, or in our case `struct`'s:

```py
from pyspark.sql.types import *
from collections import Counter

# We need to specify the schema of the return object
schema_count = ArrayType(StructType([
    StructField("word", StringType(), False),
    StructField("count", IntegerType(), False)
]))

count_udf = udf(
    lambda s: Counter(s).most_common(), 
    schema_count
)
```

Putting it all together:

```py
from pyspark.sql.functions import collect_list

(df.groupBy("id")
 .agg(collect_list("message").alias("message"))
 .withColumn("message", unpack_udf("message"))
 .withColumn("message", count_udf("message"))).show(truncate = False)
+-----------------+------------------------------------------------------+
|id               |message                                               |
+-----------------+------------------------------------------------------+
|10100718890699676|[[oecd,1], [the,1], [with,1], [at,1]]                 |
|10100720363468236|[[what,3], [me,1], [sad,1], [to,1], [does,1], [the,1]]|
+-----------------+------------------------------------------------------+
```

**Data:**

```py
df = sc.parallelize([(10100720363468236,["what", "sad", "to", "me"]),
                     (10100720363468236,["what", "what", "does", "the"]),
                     (10100718890699676,["at", "the", "oecd", "with"])]).toDF(["id", "message"])
```

Comment: Nice, seems similar to what I came up with last night. I wonder which one is more efficient?

Comment: you could try the `time` package to measure execution time. at start of code block : `start_time = time.time()`, at the end: `print("Execution time --- %s seconds ---" % (time.time() - start_time))`

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```py
from  pyspark.sql.functions import *

df.withColumn("word", explode("message")) \
  .groupBy("user_id", "word").count() \
  .groupBy("user_id") \
  .agg(collect_list(struct("word", "count")))
```