# Grouping by then applying custom function in Spark, using SparkSession in a Java stream?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

Let's assume that I have a use case where I want to `groupBy` then apply a custom function to the grouped values. In Python, I could accomplish this through:

```scala
df.groupby("id").apply(custom_function)
```

and

```py
@pandas_udf("id string, prediction double", PandasUDFType.GROUPED_MAP)
def custom_function(id, dataframe):
    rf = RandomForestRegressor(n_estimators=25, random_state=42)

    rf.fit(train_features, dataframe.quantity_sold)

    prediction = rf.predict(test_features)

    return pd.DataFrame({'id': id, 'prediction': prediction}, index=[0])
```

I could accomplish the same thing in Scala through:

```scala
input.rdd.groupBy(row => row.get(0)).collect().map(data => {
            val df = sparkSession.createDataFrame(sparkContext.parallelize(data._2.toSeq), input.schema)
 
            (data._1.toString, df)
        }).foldLeft(sparkSession.createDataFrame(sparkContext.emptyRDD[Row], outputSchema))((acc, next) => {
            val assembler = new VectorAssembler()
                .setInputCols(modelColumns)
                .setOutputCol(features)
                .transform(next._2)
 
            val forest = oldForest
                .fit(assembler)
                .transform(testAssembler)
 
            acc.union(forest)
        })
```

If we compare these two workarounds, the upper one works much faster than the below one. I tried to do this without `collect`, but I get the error `RDD transformations and actions can only be invoked by the driver, not inside of other transformations`.

I am aware that `collect` returns the results to the driver as a list, that is why I am forced to use Scala collection API (`map` and `flatMap`) to further continue my processing.

My questions regarding this are, is the job not supposed to be spread to executors again once collected to the driver (since I am continuing to use Spark ML API)? Or is everything simply calculated (once collected) in the driver as the code goes back to where `main` method is executed? Basically, why is the run very slow and is there any approach to make this process better without using Python?

Thank you!

---

**EDIT:** Managed to solve this (an example as below); say we have this dataset:

```
+---+-----+------+-----+
|id |first|second|third|
+---+-----+------+-----+
|1  |1.0  |1.0   |1.0  |
|1  |1.0  |2.0   |2.0  |
|1  |1.0  |3.0   |3.0  |
|1  |1.0  |4.0   |4.0  |
|1  |1.0  |5.0   |5.0  |
+---+-----+------+-----+
```

Our goal is to group by `id`, then for the grouped columns (`first`, `second` and `third`), we want to train the model then predict something (with column `third` being our label).

To group and apply the UDAF (as suggested from werner):

```scala
val myAggFct = udaf(MyAgg).apply(array("first", "second", "third"))

df.groupBy("id").agg(myAggFct)
```

`myAggFct` UDF is implemented as below:

```scala
object MyAgg extends Aggregator[Seq[Double], Seq[Seq[Double]], String] {
  override def zero: Seq[Seq[Double]] = scala.collection.mutable.Seq[Seq[Double]]()

  override def reduce(b: Seq[Seq[Double]], a: Seq[Double]): Seq[Seq[Double]] = b :+ a

  override def merge(b1: Seq[Seq[Double]], b2: Seq[Seq[Double]]): Seq[Seq[Double]] = b1 ++ b2

  override def finish(allInts: Seq[Seq[Double]]): String = {

    // Defining the attributes (first, second and third, as our dataset)
    val array: List[Attribute] = List() :+
      new Attribute("first") :+
      new Attribute("second") :+
      new Attribute("third")

    // Creation of the instance and defining what we want to predict, in our case, the last attribute
    // aka. `third`
    val dataRaw = new Instances("train", new util.ArrayList[Attribute](array.asJava), 0)
    dataRaw.setClassIndex(dataRaw.numAttributes() - 1)

    // Converting our Seq[Seq[Double]] to Dense Instances, so we can add it to `dataRaw`
    // aka. our trained model
    dataRaw.addAll(allInts.map(v => new DenseInstance(1.0, v.toArray)).asJava)

    // We create a Random Forest object and we use `dataRaw` as classifier
    val mlp = new RandomForest()
    mlp.buildClassifier(dataRaw)

    // Give it a test case, in this case, we want to see where first = 1.0 and second = 2.0 fall into
    val testInstance = new DenseInstance(1.0, Seq(1.0, 2.0).toArray)
    testInstance.setDataset(dataRaw)

    // We classify the instance and add some content for clearer output
    mlp.classifyInstance(testInstance).toString + ": " + allInts.mkString(", ")
  }

  override def bufferEncoder: Encoder[Seq[Seq[Double]]] = newSequenceEncoder[Seq[Seq[Double]]]

  override def outputEncoder: Encoder[String] = Encoders.STRING
}
```

Final result:

```
+---+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|id |myagg$(array(first, second, third))                                                                         |
+---+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|1  |2.2: List(1.0, 1.0, 1.0), List(1.0, 2.0, 2.0), List(1.0, 3.0, 3.0), List(1.0, 4.0, 4.0), List(1.0, 5.0, 5.0)|
+---+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

In this case, there might be some overhead while converting from/to Java and Scala.

Comment: Can you use a mix of spark and pandas? Have a look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70518400/pyspark-groupby-and-apply-a-custom-function

Comment: I have solved the use-case through `@pandas_udf` as stated in the question (hopefully clear enough); but my question is more about what really happens in this case with Spark as I find this case (collecting, then creating data sets in a map and folding left) very confusing

Comment: *The idea is to groupBy, then apply a custom function to the grouped dataset.* What is this function? And the schema of your data, or a simple dataset? This info would be very helpful.

Comment: I added more pieces of codes to the question, I hope it is clearer now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a good use case for an [User-Defined Aggregate Function](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.3.0/sql-ref-functions-udf-aggregate.html).

**What is an User-Defined Aggregate Function?**

After grouping a dataframe with [groupBy](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/Dataset.html#groupBy(col1:String,cols:String*):org.apache.spark.sql.RelationalGroupedDataset) usually one or more aggregation functions like [min](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.3.0/api/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/functions$.html#min(columnName:String):org.apache.spark.sql.Column), [max](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.3.0/api/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/functions$.html#max(columnName:String):org.apache.spark.sql.Column) or [sum](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.3.0/api/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/functions$.html#sum(columnName:String):org.apache.spark.sql.Column) are used to aggregate all values that belong to one group of rows into a single value. If none of Spark's built-in functions suits your needs you can write your own function that takes the data from one of the groups and aggregates it into a new value.

Like you can use

```scala
df.groupBy('myCol1).agg(sum('myCol2))
```

you can use

```scala
df.groupBy('myCol1).agg(customFunction('myCol2))
```

where `customFunction` does whatever you need it to do, for example applying a RandomForestRegressor to all elements of one group of data.

**How to create an User-Defined Aggregate Function?**

Here is an (arguably simplistic) example for an User-Defined Aggregate Function. This function collects all values of one group in a sequence and then concatenates all these values into a string.

```scala
import org.apache.spark.sql.expressions.Aggregator
import org.apache.spark.sql._
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
import spark.implicits._

//some test data: 1,2,3,...,10
val df = (1 to 10).toDF()

//create the user defined aggregation function
object MyAgg extends Aggregator[Int, Seq[Int], String]{
  override def zero: Seq[Int] = scala.collection.mutable.Seq[Int]()

  override def reduce(b: Seq[Int], a: Int): Seq[Int] = b :+ a

  override def merge(b1: Seq[Int], b2: Seq[Int]): Seq[Int] = b1 ++ b2

  override def finish(allInts: Seq[Int]): String = allInts.foldLeft("START")((s,b) => s + "_" + b)

  override def bufferEncoder: Encoder[Seq[Int]] = newSequenceEncoder[Seq[Int]]

  override def outputEncoder: Encoder[String] = Encoders.STRING
}
val myAggFct = udaf(MyAgg).withName("myAgg")

//group the dataframe and apply myAggFct to each group separately
df.groupBy(expr("value % 3")).agg(myAggFct('value)).show
```

Output:

```
+-----------+--------------+
|(value % 3)|  myagg(value)|
+-----------+--------------+
|          1|START_1_4_7_10|
|          2|   START_2_5_8|
|          0|   START_3_6_9|
+-----------+--------------+
```

**How does the User-Defined Aggregate Function work?**

The two functions `reduce` and `merge` combine all values of one group into a sequence created by the `zero` function.

The central function is the function `finish`. Here the sequence of all collected values (`allInts`) is transformed into the result of the aggregation operation. This would be the place to apply for example the RandomForestRegressor. As the `finish` function runs distributed on the executor nodes, all required additional data should be [broadcasted](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.3.0/rdd-programming-guide.html#broadcast-variables).

*Note*: the example above could also (better) be implemented using [Dataset.reduce](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/Dataset.html#reduce(func:org.apache.spark.api.java.function.ReduceFunction%5BT%5D):T) because we do not need the values as sequence. We simply could add the values to the string as soon as we see them. But for a regressor we need the complete list of values and so the User-Defined Aggreate Function is reasonable here.

Comment: Thank you very much for the deep explanation; in order to use Random Forest for example inside `finish`, I have to create a data frame from the list, which I don't think works (in my code, I am getting a null pointer exception) for some reason, is there someway to use the session inside `finish` method? Or do I have to try and find an external Scala / Java Random Forest library?

Comment: @vilalabinot yes, you are right. You should use an external library. Inside of `finish` you already have all the data of one group. So there is no need to use a (Spark) dataframe. However this data must fit into the memory of one executor.

Answer (score 1):

The python version actually run in the executors and hence distributes the load. [Collect requires all executors](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/rdd-programming-guide.html#actions) to send their data to the driver for processing. This means your only use the threads provided by the driver.  You are also likely suffering from lots of garbage collection as well as you are creating a Vector assembler over and over again.(and immediately throwing it away)

If you want you can do collect like things in-side of an executor. you can use  [mapPartitions](https://sparkbyexamples.com/spark/spark-map-vs-mappartitions-transformation/).

> ```
> val df4 = df2.mapPartitions(iterator => { // Start executer code
>     // Do the heavy initialization here
>     // Like database connections e.t.c
>     val util = new Util()
>     val res = iterator.map(row=>{ 
>       val fullName = util.combine(row.getString(0),row.getString(1),row.getString(2))
>       (fullName, row.getString(3),row.getInt(5)) 
>     })
>     res // End executor code
>   })
>   val df4part = df4.toDF("fullName","id","salary")
>   df4part.printSchema()
>   df4part.show(false)
> ```

The catch is that you cannot use any feature that uses sparkContext as that only lives inside the driver.  Said another way: You can only use pure scala features inside the executor code. But if you can find a Scala library for Random forest that would be answer.  The iterator used inside is very memory efficient and will run much faster than your collect that you are doing.

Likely you really want to use spark's [RandomForestRegressor](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.ml.regression.RandomForestRegressor.html)?

It look like you have a global `oldForest` so I can't tell what you are using but [a global variable] won't work with mapParitions so initialize it once and use it many times(inside the executor code)

[Collect Code](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/sql/catalyst/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/catalyst/expressions/aggregate/collect.scala)

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, the below part is very clear, however, on the top one, I think this does not hold true: `Collect requires all executors to send their data to the driver for processing` neither this: `This means your only use the threads provided by the executor`. I think it's a typo, but thank you very much!

Comment: Well respectfully it's documented that this is what happens: https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/rdd-programming-guide.html#actions

Comment: And thank you for pointing out my typo. I did mean driver not executor.